# Is it possible to link one QR code to multiple messenger BOT

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger-bot

I created a Facebook Messenger Bot(for customer's feedback) for our office last year, now we have 4 more branches and we want to have the feedback Bot at every branch. I want to know if it's possible to distinguish each branch (through the QR Code) by using the same messenger BOT we have at the head office without creating a new Messenger Bot application for each branch.

Comment: Not sure what QR code you are talking about. You can simply subscribe your app to multiple pages, what more do you need?

Comment: QR codes will be placed in each branch for users to scan and interact with the BOT( It's for feedbacks). If I subscribe to the app to multiple pages, can I know which page the message is coming from? So we can tie customers feedback to each branch. Thank you

Comment: The page id is of course part of the data structure you receive via webhook … https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webhook#format

Comment: Thank you Very much for this. I will take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for parametric codes. 
You can set `ref` values in parametric codes, and with that you can distinguish multiple branches, even though the QR code for messenger will be same from user's eye. 
You can read more about it here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/messenger-codes/